# NSCalendar dateFromComponents returns wrong value when using weeks

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsdate

So i try to get this weeks date range.

When i get current date components (only year and date) these are the values:

[image]

I noticed that there is "Obsolescent" written near week. Did try searching apple docs but found nothing about this.

Then i try to get the NSDate with current calendar (or gregorian calendar, same value) but the value i get is:

[image]

So weeks got ignored. So i added few months and one week to my components and had such components:

[image]

Then i tried to get my date out of this, this is what i got:

[image]

Now clearly week components are getting ignored here. Why is that so? Is it deprecated? Or is it some bug?

Comment: Insert code, not images.  The `{}` button on the post will format code nicely.  For values do `po endDate`, eg, in the console to list the value in text form.

Comment: Okay, will do that from now on. I just used images to prove that values are exact (i do see a lot of people answering "did you really get the correct values?").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the solution finally.

It appears that it all sorts out (starts working) if you just set weekday:

```
[startDate setWeekday:1];
```

Then the date with week is returned correctly.

Do not know if it is still a bug when week components get ignored without setting weekday.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the start end date of the a week, the `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:` method of `NSCalendar` is quite useful:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDate *startOfWeek;
NSTimeInterval length;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
                                startDate:&startOfWeek
                                 interval:&length
                                  forDate:now];
NSDate *endOfWeek = [startOfWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:length];
NSLog(@"%@", startOfWeek);
NSLog(@"%@", endOfWeek);
```

To compute the same date a week before, use `dateByAddingComponents`:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comp setWeek:-1]; // One week back in time
NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:now options:0];
NSLog(@"%@", now);
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: Yes your solution works. So i see that datebyAddingComponents with week works but dateFromComponents with week does not work. This sounds like a bug for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even though i do not have an answer to my question i will post solution to this issue that i used.

So i took weeks and multiplied them with 7. This gave me current week end date. I know it is not good since weeks can have different days set, etc. But for my most default issue (gregorian calender, 7 days a week) this solution was fast workaround in already existing date time calculator.

```
[components setDay:components.week * 7 - 7];                                //Start of week
        startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
        [components setDay:components.day + 7];                                     //End of week
        endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
        [components setDay:0];                                                      //I am using this not just here so i am setting back my changes
```

Comment: So your task is to compute the start and end of the current week?

Comment: My task is to generate two dates, that would define the meaning of "today", "yesterday" or "same day week before". So the answer is ± yes

Comment: Perhaps you can post a complete code example with the input and output. Then we might be able to point out if there is a "better" solution.

Comment: Well i cannot post you the code itself (strict policy) but i can just say that the input is a string that defines some "moving date" like "Yesterday", "SameDayWeekBefore", "LastWeek", "SameWeekYearBefore" etc. and the output is date that represents the string like May 2013 16 00:00 - 23:59 if you would calculate "Yesterday" on May 17th. Detection, calculation, everything works fine. I deal with half years, quarters (NSQuarterCalendarUnit doesn't work, apple bug) and so on. The week is the only issue here. And i tested it, and it doesn't work.